# Can OOB calendar be used as both shared and personal?

Tags: 2013, calendar, 2016

Can we use OOB calendar as both shared and personal i.e.

1. When an authorized user (I will create a new group for this purpose) adds an event then it is viewable by all users
2. When a user himself adds an event then it is only viewable by himself

I know by default it is shared that certain users can add (who have Contribute permission) and others can read (if all have read permission). And I know it can be made personal by changing list setting which will set unique permission on items.

What I want it so make personal and shared at the same time. Is it possible?